# Compiling bash from source in a custom env - custom profile is not being read

Tags: bash, compiling

I just compiled `bash 4.4.12` for my arm-based NAS. 
The NAS has a custom environment. The prefix is `/ffp/` instead of `/usr/`.

Starting the fresh compiled bash `/ffp/etc/profile/` is not beeing read/sourced.
Is this a `./configure` flag, or do I need to specify this elsewhere?

My compile config. looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
OLANG=$LANG
export LANG="C"

[ -x ./autogen.sh ] && ./autogen.sh

if [ -x ./configure ]; then
./configure \
--prefix=/ffp/ \
--bindir=/ffp/bin/ \
--sbindir=/ffp/sbin/ \
--sysconfdir=/ffp/etc \
--localstatedir=/ffp/var \
--libdir=/ffp/lib/ \
--includedir=/ffp/include/ \
--datarootdir=/ffp/share/\
--libexecdir=/ffp/libexec/
fi
make
make strip
make install

export LANG=$OLANG
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hardcoded in `pathnames.h.in`:

```
/* The default login shell startup file. */
#define SYS_PROFILE "/etc/profile"
```

You can just replace it with what you want and rebuild.